# Using Linq's GroupBy function, but padding data with zeros when none exists?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using linq to shape objects returned from the database to better translate into JSON data to use with third party controls (such as highcharts). When shaping the data, I need to make sure values exist for each data-point, even if they are zero.

For example, when querying the database, I may get back a list of the following object:

```
public class DatabaseResponse
{
    public string TypeOfService {get;set;}
    public string FacilityName {get;set;}
    public int ServiceCount {get;set;}
}
```

Now the database may return any number of these objects and sometimes their different `TypeOfService` strings match. Other times they do not. When I shape the data, I need to return a couple different pieces of data. Namely, the categories (an array of the FacilityNames) and their `ServiceCount` for each respective `TypeOfService`.

Originally I was doing something like the following to get the categories:

```
var result = GetTypeOfServiceCountsByFacility(startDate, endDate, companyDivisionIds, facilityIds, catcCompanyId);
```

And I was doing something like this to get the service counts:

```
var data = result.OrderBy(n => n.FacilityName).GroupBy(n => n.TypeOfService).Select(n => new {
    name = n.Key,
    data = n.Select(x => x.ServiceCount).ToArray()
});
```

The above works perfectly if each Facility has matching Services, but if they are off, the arrays are off. Is there a simple way to pad the data to ensure that everything gets populated (even if it's just zeros)?

**EDIT**

Example input:

```
var result = new List<ServiceTypeFacilityCounts>
{
    { new ServiceTypeFacilityCounts {FacilityName = "Facility 2", TypeOfService="Phone", ServiceCount=50 } },
    { new ServiceTypeFacilityCounts {FacilityName = "Facility 2", TypeOfService="Visit", ServiceCount=10 } },
    { new ServiceTypeFacilityCounts {FacilityName = "Facility 2", TypeOfService="Call-In", ServiceCount=3 } },
    { new ServiceTypeFacilityCounts {FacilityName = "Facility 1", TypeOfService="Phone", ServiceCount=5 } }
};
```

with my above code my output would be:

```
categories = ["Facility 1", Facility 2"]
data = { 
            [{name: "Phone", data: [5,50]}],
            [{name: "Visit", data: [10]}],
            [{name: "Call-In", data: [3]}]
       }
```

But in reality it should be:

```
categories = ["Facility 1", Facility 2"]
data = { 
            [{name: "Phone", data: [5,50]}],
            [{name: "Visit", data: [0,10]}],
            [{name: "Call-In", data: [0,3]}]
       }
```

Comment: Could you add example data and corresponding expected output?

Comment: @mayu I've updated my original question to contain some example input and output.

Comment: If phone was there 3 times, would the we pad visit to [0,0,10]?

Comment: @mayu yes, as long as it belonged to something like `Facility 3`. No one facility will have duplicates of a certain type of service, but there is a good chance a facility won't have a given service type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially doing a left join on the inner data items.  Write it as so:

```
var facilities = results.Select(x => x.FacilityName).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var query =
    from x in results
    group x by x.TypeOfService into g
    select new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Data =
            (from c in facilities
            join x in g on c equals x.FacilityName into xs
            from x in xs.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select x?.ServiceCount ?? 0).ToArray()
    };
```

Here's an equivalent version of the above query using the method syntax.

```
var facilities = results.Select(x => x.FacilityName).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var query = results.GroupBy(x => x.TypeOfService)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Data = facilities.GroupJoin(g, c => c, x => x.FacilityName, (c, xs) => xs)
            .SelectMany(xs =>
                xs.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => x?.ServiceCount ?? 0)
            ).ToArray(),
    });
```

Comment: For consistency sake, is the a easy to use linq method syntax to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. But either approach whether it's using the query syntax or method call syntax are mostly equivalent. There's some operations not compatible with another (such as `Distinct` calls). Personally, I would use the syntax that looks cleaner, usually that's the query syntax. But I will try to avoid whenever possible mixing between the two too much. If it's unavoidable, placing subqueries in separate variables/functions generally makes it much cleaner.

Comment: Understood, I've just pretty much only ever used the method syntax, and our entire code-base is only using that so far. I was just trying to see the equivalent version in method syntax, but I'm sure I can whip something up. I know method syntax joins can get nasty.

Comment: Oh yeah, the method syntax can get really gnarly especially when group joins or other nested from clauses are mixed in. I'll add a translation to the method syntax. There's no one way to do it, but it can be written in a way that is close enough to the query syntax.

Comment: Perfect, the SelectMany and DefaultIfEmpty methods were two methods I didn't know much about! Great example.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I've come up with is to build an interim list that forcefully iterates over both the categories list and the grouped service types. I then try to select out of the main result-set to see if a value exists. If one does, I add it to the new list. If it doesn't I add zero to the new list. That version looks like:

```
var categories = result.OrderBy(n => n.FacilityName).Select(n => n.FacilityName).Distinct().ToArray();
var paddedData = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();

result.OrderBy(n => n.FacilityName).GroupBy(n => n.TypeOfService).ToList().ForEach(n =>
{
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        var newItem = new Tuple<string,int>
        (
            n.Key,
            result.FirstOrDefault(item => item.FacilityName == category && item.TypeOfService == n.Key)?.ServiceCount ?? 0
        );
        paddedData.Add(newItem);
    }
});

var data = paddedData.GroupBy(n => n.Item1).Select(n => new
{
    name = n.Key,
    data = n.Select(x => x.Item2).ToArray()
});
var shapedData = new
{
    series = data,
    categories
};
```